# I can't make my navigation bar text links horizontal?

Tags: html, css

I have spent a while trying to find out how to make text links sit horizontally on a navigation bar, but to no success.I am EXTREMELY new to coding so this is probably extremely easy to do, i am using html and CSS, i have tried just putting them on the same line. Also using:

```
#nav li a {
    color: black;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav li a {
    color: black;
    position: relative; 
}
```

i have tried to find the answer on the site but i cant see one, so i thought i might as well just ask people. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3):

You are targeting the wrong element, it should be

```
#nav li {
   display: inline;
}
```

You were selecting `a` element, you need to target the `li`, `a` is an `inline` element by default, `li` renders one below the other, so to make them inline, we target `li`

I would suggest you to use

```
#nav li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: -4px; /* If that white space matters to you */
}
```

As you will get same effect, but with some additional bonus like `margins padding` to space up your element. Alternatively, you can also use `float: left;` but you will need to `clear` your floats so stick with `inline-block`

Comment: I have just tried it but it didn't work, thank you for trying